# Is it possible to customize the contents of the Clear button in react-bootstrap-typeahead?

Tags: font-awesome, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Using [react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead) is it possible to change the contents of the Clear button?

I need to include a FontAwesome icon and "CLEAR" text to match a design.

Looking at the [[RBT] Custom Aux Components](https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-custom-aux-components-gn3kn?file=/src/index.js) demo I can see the `ClearButton` component, but I can't see how to customize this. I tried changing the `label` prop but this had no effect:

`<ClearButton onClick={onClear} label="CLEAR" />`

Is it possible to add:

1. label text
2. a FontAwesome icon

to the Clear button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize `ClearButton` itself, but you can follow the example you linked to and use your own clear/close button component:

```
<Typeahead ... >
  {({ onClear, selected }) => (
    <div className="rbt-aux">
      {!!selected.length && <MyCloseButton onClick={onClear} />}
    </div>
  )}
</Typeahead>
```

Note that `ClearButton` isn't really anything special; it just encapsulates the markup and classnames for Bootstrap's [Close Button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/close-icon/) into a component. Feel free to use your own button!

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer, and most importantly for writing the awesome library ;)